# Validator for current password, new password and confirm new password laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, passwords, confirmation

Hi there I am having trouble on validation this is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\website\settings;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\PasswordAccountRequest;
use Auth;
use Hash; 
use App\User;
use Validator;

class AccountSettingsController extends Controller
{
    public function changepassword(){

        return view('website.settings.account.password');
    }
    public function newpassword(PasswordAccountRequest $request){

        $auth_user_password =  Auth::user()->password; 
        $new_password = bcrypt($request['new_password']);


        if (Hash::check($request->input('current_password'), $auth_user_password)) {

            $user_profile = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->update(['password' => $new_password]);  


                }

                return redirect()->back()->with(['status' => 'Password changed successfully.']);    

     }
}
```

Here I have my form on blade:

```
<form role="form" class="form" action="{{ url('/settings/password-change') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}  
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="notifications-label"> @lang('general.change_account_pass') </label><br>
            <label class="will-recieve-notifications">@lang('general.requested_a_pass_change') </label>
        </div>
    </div>
<br> 

    <div class="row padding-30 padding-top-bottomm-0">

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group floating-label {{ $errors->has('current_password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="current_password"  id="regular2" type="text" value="" >
                                        <label for="regular2">@lang('general.current_password')</label>
                                        @if ($errors->has('current_password'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('current_password') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                        @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                            <div class="row padding-30 padding-top-bottomm-0">

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group floating-label {{ $errors->has('new_password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="new_password"  id="regular2" type="text" value="" >
                                        <label for="regular2">@lang('general.new_password')</label>
                                        @if ($errors->has('new_password'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('new_password') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                        @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div> 
                            <div class="row padding-30 padding-top-bottomm-0">

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group floating-label {{ $errors->has('new_password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="confirm_new_password"  id="regular2" type="text" value="" >
                                        <label for="regular2">@lang('general.confirm_new_password')</label>
                                        @if ($errors->has('new_password'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('new_password') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                        @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                             <div class="row settings-footer">
        <div class="col-md-12 padding-0">
            <button type="submit" class="btn save-lang">@lang('buttons.save_changes')</button>
        </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

And this is my model where I put my validations:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class PasswordAccountRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;

    } 

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
                'current_password'         => 'required',
                'new_password'             => 'required ',
                'confirm_password'         => 'required |same:new_password',
            ]; 
    }
}
```

As you can see on controller I am using  tha Hash check to compare the password the users types on the form with the old password. How is it possible to make the validation if the old password is wrong to show the validation message like this :
[image]

And for the other two the new password with the confirm new password when its not the same to show the message like this:
[image]

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom validation rule that checks if the current password is correct.

Then, in your blade file you can add conditional to display error message with current password field.

If you are using laravel >=5.5, you can create a rule class using

```
php artisan make:rule IsCurrentPassword
```

*If you are using laravel < 5.5, you can create a custom validation with same logic.*

Your passes method may seem like this:

```
public function __construct($user)
{
     $this->user = $user;
 }
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return Hash::check($value, $user->password);
}
```

You can use `message` method to return a custom error message.

Then in your validation array

```
[
    'current_password' => [ ... , new IsCurrentPassword (auth()->user()), ..],
    ...
]
```